# Angular: Запрос на получение нового токена через интерсептор

Tags: angular, jwt, аутентификация

Есть сервер который после аутентификации отдает 2 токена access и refresh. На клиенте я получаю их и ложу в local storage. Я выковал интерсептор который к каждому запросу вешает access token из local storage. Проблема в том что когда время access токена истекает, мне прилетает естественная ошибка 403. Я бы хотел найти способ в интерсепторе после отправки запроса наблюдать за ответом и сделать запрос на получение новых токенов при возникновении данной ошибки.

Сейчас имеется такой код:

**Service**

```
login(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/login`, formData)
    .pipe(
      tap(response => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response['access_token']);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response['refresh_token']);
      })
   );
}
```

**Interceptor**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(!!localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
        const clone = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('Authorization',
                `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`)
        });
        return next.handle(clone); // Здесь нужно обработать 403 ошибку
        // 1. Делать новый запрос к серваку на получение токенов
        // 2. Повторить логику метода
    }
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

Провальная попытка:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(!!localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
        const clone = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('Authorization',
                `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`)
        });
        return next.handle(clone).pipe(
            tap((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                if(event.type == 0) {
                    // Так наверное делать нельзя
                    this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/token/refresh`, {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')}`
                        }
                    })
                        // Call stack error, а как иначе?))
                        .subscribe(response => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response['access_token']);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response['refresh_token']);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }),
        );
    }
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать RxJS операторы `catchError` для отлова ошибок и `switchMap` для обработки внутренних Observable (грубо говоря "подписка в подписке").

Пример отлавливания нужной ошибки и обновления токена:

```
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError((error) => { // Отлавливаем ошибку
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) { // Проверяем тип необходимой ошибки
            return refreshToken().pipe( // Вызываем некую функцию по обновлению токена
              switchMap(() => {
                const request = req.clone({
                  headers: req.headers.append('Authorization',
                    `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`)
                });
                return next.handle(request); // Заново вызываем упавший запрос с обновленным токеном
              })
            );
          }
          return throwError(error); // Пробрасываем необработанные ошибки дальше
        }));
```

В примере `refreshToken()` - это некая функция по обновлению/записи токена, которая возвращает `Observable`.